# How to remove double quotation marks from words and numbers in a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have `51,823` lines from a `.txt` file. Each line in the text file looks like this:

```
"word","word2",number,number2,"number3"
```

I've stripped and split each line into individual lists that look like this:

```
['"word"', '"word2"', 'number', 'number2' '"number3"']
```

All words have double quotation marks and some numbers have double quotation marks. I want to remove all the double quotation marks so my lists looks like this:

```
['word', 'word2', 'number', 'number2', 'number3']
```

This is the code:

```
file = open('somefile.txt', 'r')
data = []
for line in file:
    parts = line.strip().split(',')
    data.append(parts)
```

How do I remove the double quotation marks before appending to the list?

Comment: `parts = [word.strip('"') for word in line.strip().split(',')]`

Comment: use `csv` module to read this file. It should remove quotation automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
...
parts = [x.replace('"', '') for x in line.strip().split(',')]
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this using `list-comprehension` :

```
a = ['"word"', '"word2"', 'number', 'number2', '"number3"']
vals = [i[1:-1] if i[0] == '\"' else i for i in a]
```

Comment: Thank you for responding Jarvis :)

Comment: Do upvote the answer if you like my approach :) @rsmalley74

Comment: Done. Thanks Jarvis.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to achieve that:

```
import re

l = ['"word"', '"word2"', 'number', 'number2', '"number3"']
res = re.findall('\w+', ' '.join(l))
```

**Output:**

```
>>> res
['word', 'word2', 'number', 'number2', 'number3']
```

Comment: Thank you ettanany!  You guys are much better at this than I am!